# How to remove ENG from taskbar at Windows using automated batch file always

Tags: batch-file, automation, taskbar

keyboard layout displaying ENG near date and time at windows (3 different versions of Windows at 3 different systems).

Here goes the steps I tried:

```
Start =>
Advanced keyboard settings =>
disable the tick mark for: "Use the desktop language bar when it's available"
Enable the tick mark again.
ENG disappears near the date and time at Windows.
```

I am doing this action 1/2/3 days once always to disable that ENG near date and time.
I am facing this useless ENG for last 2/3 years.
Reason:
I want number of apps at taskbar to be limited from 2003 to till now.
How to disable that ENG option always using automation ?
I viewed the values before and after reboot without using automation:
a)

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\CTF\LangBar /f /v ShowStatus /t REG_DWORD /d 3
```

b)

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\CTF\LangBar /f /v ShowStatus /t REG_DWORD /d 4
```

Other test result:
If I disable or enable ENG the values at `LangBar` never change(even after reboot).

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\CTF\LangBar"

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CTF\LangBar
    ShowStatus    REG_DWORD    0x3
    Transparency    REG_DWORD    0xff
    Label    REG_DWORD    0x0
    ExtraIconsOnMinimized    REG_DWORD    0x0
```

If I achieve this using a batch file:
I can keep the shortcut of that batch file following directory:

Daily after login:
I always press start menu => Advanced keyboard settings => disable the option for => Use the desktop language bar whent it's available => enable the same option again at => Use the desktop language bar whent it's available
ENG disappears.

```
$# %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
$ echo murugesan openssl | sed "s/./:( /g;"
:( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :(
$ ./76585804.sh
START_DATE: 000 Fri 30-Jun-2023 OF MY TIME PASS.
WAIT_DAYS:  018 Mon 17-Jul-2023
TODAY:      000 Tue 18-Jul-2023 BREAKING TODAY LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my happiness today :)
Here goes the steps to remove ENG:

1. Press start menu
2. search and click Settings
3. At left pane => Click Time & language
4. At right pane => Click Language & region
5. At right pane => If Preferred languages having more than one option:
   a. English (India/Japan/Singapore/United kingdom/United States/...)
   b. Tamil (India)
   I have written a. b. options using sorted order.
   I have not written using "tac" since I cannot make our earth to rotate at reverse order :) inside our universe.
   Click ... at first language
   Click Move down
   Click ... at second language
   Click Remove
   Press yes
   Remove all languages excluding your selected single language.